# Is it possible a whole class object from one movieclip to another?

Tags: flash

Any sample code to do so ? I can only see example for passing simple variable.

Let's say I have a movieClip M1 and a movieClip M2 loaded by M1. Then M2 will create an instance of a class c that will be passed to MovieClip M1 by calling a predefined method.

I'm totally new to actionscript so I'd need to know the exact syntax and event to do so.

Comment: Are there words missing from your question? I think you should elaborate!

Comment: ok thanks for the remark I have elaborated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass them the same way you pass *simple variables*.

```
function myFunction(a:CustomClass):void
{
  trace("received " + a.toString());
}

var c:CustomClass = new CustomClass("blah", 42);
myFunciton(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import my.class.a;

class b {
    var test:A = new A;
}
```

this is an abstract version, hope you can use it.

Comment: thanks but I don't understand your answer : you only instantiate the class A in B. It doesn't show me how to pass class A to B.